# Duas condições no Where não trazem um resultado

Tags: query, oracle, where, oracle12c

Estou fazendo uma query no Oracle Database 12C e estou com um problema: quero que somente os produtos que tenham **endereco_1 como 'A'** apareçam no meu `ResultSelect`.

No exemplo abaixo o item de "código: 312107" ele tem dois endereços: 'P' e o 'A' e eu quero que meu `select` traga **todos** os itens que possuam **apenas** o endereço 'A'.

Se eu filtro no `WHERE endereco_1 not in ('P','S','V')` **ou** `endereco_1 =
'A'` esse produto abaixo vai continuar aparecendo.

Eu preciso de uma condição onde se o produto tiver `('P' + 'A')` no `endereco_1` então não aparece no `resultselect`, se tiver **somente** 'A' **e nada mais**, pode aparecer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Augusto, não consegui ver seu print, mas veja se algo na linha abaixo te ajuda:
    SELECT * FROM TABELA A1 
    WHERE A1.ENDERECO = 'A'
    AND A1.ID NOT IN (
     SELECT A2.ID FROM TABELA A2
     WHERE A2.ENDERECO IN ('P', 'S', 'V'))

Answer (score 1):

Tenta este SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUTOS AS PR1
WHERE ENDERECO_1='A' 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PRODUTOS AS PR2 WHERE PR1.CODIGO=PR2.CODIGO AND ENDERECO_1<>'A')=0
```

Qualquer coisa é só me chamar.

Comment: Fabiano, Deu SUPER certo! Estava validando aqui e não achei produtos igual do print. Você pode me explicar a logica que você usou, o porque do COUNT e o = 0 no fim ? Deu certo, mas gostaria de entender exatamente o que essa subquery fez. Você é o cara

Comment: Oi @AugustoS , neste trecho eu contabilizo os registros que possuem o mesmo CODIGO na consulta principal e na subconsulta mas que têm ENDERECO_1 diferente de "A" e utilizo o resultado deste COUNT como parâmetro para a consulta principal.
Em outras palavras a consulta principal traz todos os produtos que possuem ENDERECO_1='A' e que possuem (ENDERECO_1<>'A') igual a zero.

Comment: Olá @AugustoS não leva a mal, mas se resposta te ajudou dá um voto positivo. Pois isso ajuda a outras pessoas encontrarem esta solução. Abraço.

Comment: Desculpe, ainda não sei mexer direito no fórum, mas ajudou sim, dei meu voto, tem como marcar concluído ou algo assim também? Obrigado por tudo!

Comment: Sem problema @AugustoS, a ideia é votar positivo nas perguntas e respostas que forem úteis e negativo se não forem. Abraço.